For $M,C\subset S_n,|M|=|C|$ find subsets of $M$ and $C$ that generate isomorphic subgroups of $S_n$ and the isomorphism maps these subsets together
I have sets $M,C \subset S_n$, s.t. $|M| = |C| \gg 1$. Given $a \in S_n$ I can determine whether $a \in M$ but I have no way to determine whether $a \in C$, however, if we assume C is numbered for given $i ≥ 1$ I can easily construct the i-th element of C. It also turns out that $\langle M \rangle = \langle C \rangle = S_n$.
I need to generate two large isomorphic subgroups of $S_n$ using subsets of $M$ and $C$ so that the isomorphism would map these subsets to each other. In other words I want to find subsets $S \subset M$ and $P \subset C$, so that the subgroups $\langle S \rangle$ and $\langle P \rangle$ would be isomorphic, and this isomorphism would map $S$ to $P$ and vice versa. In the perfect case these subgroups completely cover $M$ and $C$ whereas in the good case they cover most of $M$ and $C$.
I have already found small $\mathscr{M} \subset M$ and $\mathscr{C} \subset C$ that do generate $S_n$. The only problem is that generally the orders of the elements of these subsets do not match, so there's no automorphism that would map $\mathscr{M}$ and $\mathscr{C}$ to each other.
A simple approach would be to look for elements of the same order from $M$ and $C$ and match them together. Although, I'm not sure how practical it is.
Without further assumptions on $M$ and $C$, how difficult potentially is this problem?
